# Are $x^2$ and $x \cdot |x|$ linearly dependent on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f_1(x)=x^2, f_2(x)=x \cdot |x|$ , then they are linearly dependent on $[0,\infty)$, and also linearly dependent on $(-\infty,0]$. But the question is, are they linearly dependent on $(-\infty,\infty)$?

They should be linearly dependent as on both the interval $[0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0]$, the functions are linearly dependent. But they are linearly independent as given in my reference book.

Comment: Why don't you set up the definition of linear dependence?

Comment: Which theorem are you using when you said "it should be linearly dependent as ... " ?

Comment: as it is linearly dependent on both the interval so it should be ....

Comment: Are there non-zero solutions for $(a,b)$ such that $af_1 + bf_2 = 0, \forall x$?

Comment: @mSourav That is not a theorem I have heard of. You should at least try to prove the statement. And it is easier to show they are linearly independent by definition.

Comment: When you consider them functions over $[0,\infty)$, functions over $(-\infty,0]$, and functions over $(-\infty,\infty)$, you are actually considering three **different** vector spaces and pairs of vectors. That is, you are looking at six different vectors, in three different vector spaces. You can’t “import” information from one vector space to another just because the formulas you use to define the vectors look similar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the vector space $\mathscr{C}(\Bbb R)$ of functions $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$. Our two functions $f_1, f_2\in\mathscr{C}(\Bbb R)$ are defined by $f_1(x)=x^2$ and $f_2(x)=x\cdot\lvert x\rvert$. To see that $\{f_1, f_2\}$ is linearly independent, suppose that
$$
c_1\cdot f_1+c_2\cdot f_2=0\tag{$\ast$}
$$
where $c_1, c_2\in\Bbb R$. This equation means that
$$
c_1\cdot x^2+c_2\cdot x\cdot\lvert x\rvert=0
$$
for all $x\in\Bbb R$. Plugging in $x=-1$ and $x=1$ gives the system of linear equations
$$
\begin{array}{rcrcrc}
c_1 &-& c_2 &=& 0 \\
c_1 &+& c_2 &=& 0
\end{array}
$$
How many solutions are there to this system of equations?

Answer (score 1):

If two functions, each of which is identically not zero, are linearly dependent, then the first must be the linear combination of the second:
$$f_1=cf_2 \\ x^2=c\cdot x|x| \Rightarrow \begin{cases}c> 0, if \ \ x> 0\\ c< 0, if \ \ x< 0\\ c\in \mathbb R, if \ \ x=0\\   \end{cases}$$
However, there is no unique $c$, for which $x^2=c\cdot x|x|$ holds true for all $x\in \mathbb R$. Hence, the two functions are independent for $x\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: A set of two vectors is linearly dependent if and only if one is a scalar multiple of the other; in general, you cannot assert a priori that the first is a multiple of the second, though you can do that after you observe that the second is not the zero vector. Note that $v$ and $\mathbf{0}$ are always linearly dependent, but $v$ is not a a multiple of $\mathbf{0}$ unless they are both $\mathbf{0}$.

Comment: If one vector is equal to the sum of scalar multiples of other vectors, it is said to be a linear combination of the other vectors... It is not assertion, but a necessary and sufficient condition, which fails in this situation, no?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, please, see if the update is suitable now?

Comment: Yes, the statement is now correct. The problem you had is that you went from “if two vectors are linearly dependent” to “the first is a multiple of the second”. While the latter statement implies the first, the first may hold while the second is false, because of the example I gave.

Answer (score 1):

Hint for a  short way : just draw graphs of both functions and look whether they are scalar multiple of each other .