# Does $x^2$ and $x|x|$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Does $x^2$ and $x|x|$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$

$\textbf{Solution i tried}$- The given functions are  $x^2$ and $x|x|$

as we can se that for $[0, \infty)$ the given function $x|x|$ will become $x^2$

and then $x^2 $ cab be obtained from $x^2$ so they are linearly dependend.

similarly for $(-\infty,0)$ we get $x|x|$ as $-x^2$ which is again can be produced from $x^2$

so from this we can conclude that they are linearly dependend.

please check my solution ,if possible make some improvement in my answer

edit -it is $x^2$ and $x|x|$

Thankyou

Comment: no, for |x| and x|x| to be linearly dependent over $\mathbb R$ you would need to find $a,b\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ so that $a|x|+bx|x|=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$

Comment: sometimes you wrote $x$ and $x|x|$ and other times you wrote $|x|$ and $x|x|$; that seems inconsistent, though may not change the answer

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3102020/are-x2-and-x-cdot-x-linearly-dependent-on-mathbbr?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $ax+b x|x|=0$ for all $x$. Then, for $x >0$,  $ax+bx^{2}=0$ which gives $a+bx=0$ for all $x>0$. Put $x=1$ and $x=2$ to get $a+b=a+2b=0$. From this it is easy to see that $a=b=0$. Hence the functions are linearly independent.

Answer for the revised question: The functions are linearly dependent on $(0,\infty)$ as well as $(-\infty,0)$ but that does not mean the are linearly dependent on $\mathbb R$. So your argument is not valid.

Suppose $ax^{2}+bx|x|=0$ for all $x$. Put $x=1$ to get $a+b=0$ and put $x =-1$ to get $a-b=0$. These two equations simplify to $a=b=0$, so the functions are linearly independent.

Comment: okk its my mistake i put |x| insted of $x^2$

Comment: @TheStudent I have edited my answer.

Comment: what is wrong in my solution can you please explain?

Comment: @TheStudent I have added an expalnation.

Comment: but why this happened ,if function is $L.D$ on $(0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0]$  then how can be $L.I$ on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @TheStudent $f$ and $g$ are LD on $\mathbb R$ iff there exist constants $a, b$ not both zero such that $af(x)+b(x)=0$ fro all $x \in \mathbb R$. In this definition the same scalars $a$ and $b$ have to satisfy the equation for al real values of $x$. In your proof you are suing one set of values for the positive real line and another set of values for the negative  real line and that is not permitted.

Comment: Now i got this ,Thankyou sir.whenever i see $L.D$ or $L.I$ question i will apply this method.

Comment: one more question sir,why wronskian is also showing that they are  linear dependent.

Comment: But Linear independence and independence is with respect to some field. Here I dont think $(0,\infty)$ or the other interval is a field.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your solution is that you're breaking $\mathbb R$ up into two segments and considering linear independence on each segment. You need to consider these as functions on all of $\mathbb R$.

---

Try starting with the following approach:

Suppose that $c_1|x|+c_2x|x|=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$. Now can you show that $c_1=c_2=0$?.

Spoiler:

> In particular, evaluate at $x=\pm 1$ to get $$\begin{cases}c_1+c_2=0 \\ c_1-c_2=0\end{cases}$$ and this system has only the trivial solution, thus the functions are linearly independent.

Comment: Alternate way to solve the linear independence equation: Suppose $x\ne 0$, then $c_1 +c_2x=0 \; \forall x\ne 0$, hence $c_1=c_2=0$.